# Binding a ComboBox SelectedValue to a Nullable(Of Integer) property throws InvalidCastException

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0, vb.net-2010

I have a ViewModel class (instantiated as ilvm) with a Nullable(Of Integer) property on it called LinkedCompanyID which is manually bound to the SelectedValue on a ComboBox.  A user selecting a value from the list causes the combobox to throw an InvalidCastException.  I have done this before with other classes, the difference being that these were bound via a BindingSource, rather than directly as shown below.  The reason that I have to bind directly is that the class is derived from a ComponentModel which seems to render the individual properties invisible to a BindingSource.

```
<Browsable(False), Bindable(True)>
<DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
Public Property LinkedCompanyID As Integer?
    Get
        If Not DesignMode AndAlso _currentEntity IsNot Nothing Then
            Return _currentEntity.LinkedCompanyID
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer?)
        If Not DesignMode AndAlso _currentEntity IsNot Nothing Then
            If Not EqualityComparer(Of Integer?).Default.Equals(_currentEntity.LinkedCompanyID, value) Then
                _currentEntity.LinkedCompanyID = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LinkedCompanyID")
            End If
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

The binding is in the form Load event:

```
.
.
.

        Dim linkedCompanyBinding As Binding = New Binding("SelectedValue", ilvm, "LinkedCompanyID", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
        AddHandler linkedCompanyBinding.Parse, AddressOf parseNullableInteger
        Me.cmbLinkedCompany.DataBindings.Add(linkedCompanyBinding)
```

The list is defined as:

```
IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of integer?, string))
```

With the DisplayMember set to 'Value' and the ValueMember set to 'Key'.

When the user selects a value from the combobox list, an InvalidCastException is thrown indicating that it cannot convert from an Int32 to a Nullable(Of Integer).

In desperation I added the parseNullableInteger method:

```
Private Sub parseNullableInteger(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs)
    If e.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(e.Value) Then
        e.Value = Convert.ChangeType(e.Value, e.DesiredType)
    Else
        e.Value = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

This also does not work and in fact generates its own InvalidCastException when it tries to convert an Integer to a Nullable Integer.  Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Thanks, Neil

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I spent some time working on this and finally realized that this works when the object is assigned to the DataSource of a BindingSource rather than binding the control value to the property directly.  The BindingSource adds the magic that translates between the ComboBox Value and the Nullable Property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to expand on my comment.  The View Model is bound to a BindingSource as the DataSource and then the controls are bound to the BindingSource and the ComboBox works correctly.

e.g.

```
dim ilvmBindingSource as New BindingSource
ilvmBindingSource.DataSource = ilvm
cmbLinkedCompany.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", ilvmBIndingSource, "LinkedCompanyID", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

This basically does the job of handling the 'strange' values coming out of the ComboBox.